# java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect Response data in JMeter

Tags: java, linux, network-programming, jmeter, redhat

I am trying to send HTTP request through HTTP sampler to linux server (Red Hat), in local intranet environment.

[image: HTTP SAMPLER REQUEST]

I am getting this exception in Response Data

[image: RESPONSE DATA]

Please guide me.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that your JMeter isn't capable for establishing connection. If you can access this site with a browser you're behind a proxy.

There are 2 options on how to record scripts from behind a proxy:

- Run JMeter specifying proxy host, port, username and password as follows:

  ```
  jmeter -H (IP address or hostname of your proxy server) -P (port of your proxy server) -u (username, if required) -a (password, if required)
  ```

Example: `jmeter -H 10.10.10.1 -P 3128`

- Use [JMeter Extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en). In this case you won't need to care about proxies, certificates, headers, etc. and will be able to record tests to .jmx files right from browser.

Answer (score 0):

First ping the host; you are trying to connect. If ping working try telnet  <80> ... It is a network issue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate in detail. How should i ping telnet <80> ... ?

Comment: 1. telnet <host/ip> <port> (on dos/console prompt)